Set env variables based on JSON string
I have a string that contains a JSON array. Each element of the array is another string. And for each element of the array, I want to end up with an environment variable with a name that is based on that string.
An example might make it clearer. I have this:
json='["foo", "bar", "baz"]'

And I want to end up with these environment variables:
FOO_VAR=1
BAR_VAR=1
BAZ_VAR=1

I guess there are two steps:

Convert JSON to a bash array
Walk the bash array, munging each string and setting a variable

I can probably do step 2, but I'm stuck on step 1.
Update: With help from ChatGPT, I ended up with this.
#!/bin/bash

# Your JSON string
json='["foo", "bar", "baz"]'

# Convert JSON array to Bash array
mapfile -t arr < <(echo "$json" | jq -r '.[]')

# Iterate over each element
for item in "${arr[@]}"; do
  # Convert to uppercase and append '_VAR'
  var_name="${item^^}_VAR"
  # Export the environment variable with value 1
  export "$var_name"=1
done

# Optional: Print the variables to verify
echo "FOO_VAR=$FOO_VAR"
echo "BAR_VAR=$BAR_VAR"
echo "BAZ_VAR=$BAZ_VAR"


You could use jq to process JSON in Bash. Make it generate strings that can be sourced with .:
. <(jq -r '"export \(.[] | ascii_upcase)_VAR=1"' <<< "$json")

echo "$FOO_VAR" # prints 1

Depending on where your input, and where the value (if 1 was just a placeholder) come from, you may want to include @sh in some form.

As for specifically converting the JSON array into a Bash indexed array, make jq generate a string that can be used with declare -a:
unset arr; declare -a arr="($(jq -r '@sh' <<< "$json"))"

echo "${arr[0]}" # prints foo


You have to be confident with content of your json!!
